# Regex to match all sentences with quotes in them

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match all sentences that contain quotes, independent of the length of the quote or the number of sentences within the quote.

As Alfe point out, getting a perfect regex is maybe not viable, but I would like to improve the one I am using if possible.

Right now I am doing this to find the quote:

```
def split_by_quotes(text):
    pattern = r'([A-Z].*?\".*?\".*?\.)'
    quotes = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return(quotes)
```

But I want to make sure that the quote is appearing in a sentence and then capture that entire sentence.

By a sentence I mean a piece of text that:

1. is usually preceded by a space
2. starts with an upper case character or a quote
3. ends with either a . or ! or ? or (sometimes directly followed by a " or ')
4. is usually followed by a space

This won't capture all sentences as Alfe points out, but it would be good enough if I could match on those conditions.

For example:

> "This is a quote, it should be matched"
>
> This is text without a quote on a new line after multiple carriage returns, it should not be matched.

More complex example:

> Charles Babbage said: "On two occasions, I have been asked [by members of Parliament], 'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?' I am not able to rightly apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."

That whole sentence would match.

But,

> They called Garfield Minus Garfield and Lolcats, but when Johnson saw what he considered to be a particularly hilarious clip of someone falling down and then being "played off stage" by a cat with a keyboard, his friends thought it was lame. "I said, this is going to be big.", he says, "My friends were like, 'Nah, it's just a cat.'"

Would be matched as follows:

> They called Garfield Minus Garfield and Lolcats, but when Johnson saw what he considered to be a particularly hilarious clip of someone falling down and then being "played off stage" by a cat with a keyboard, his friends thought it was lame.

and

> "I said, this is going to be big.", he says, "My friends were like, 'Nah, it's just a cat.'"

Comment: The punctuation in your last example seems odd to me.  Surely it should be   ``"I said, this is going to be big.", he says, "My friends were like, 'Nah,' it's just a cat.'"``

Comment: Need to get my head around regex, it is sort of frustrating me at the moment. @Vorsprung Thanks, I think you are correct. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Hello. What do you call a sentence ? With your pattern, you won't catch something that extends on several lines, because the pattern's dot doesn't match the newline ``\n``. Why do you catch what's in front of the first quote and not after ?

Comment: @eyquem Thanks, I updated the regex pattern. I am using: ([A-Z].*?\".*?\".*?\.)

Comment: I am french. The words "phrase" and "sentence" are very confusingly translated between french an english. The french word _phrase_ designates, in a text, anything that is between two dots, and the french word _sentence_ designates what is named as condamnation or maxim in english. But when I read the english words **phrase** and **sentence**, I never understand clearly and unambiguously what is designated by them. So I hardly understand your question

Comment: You have an odd number of ' in `"My friends were like, 'Nah,' it's just a cat.'"`. Is that wanted?

Comment: Thanks @damienfrancois fixing that now. I will also clarify the sentence/phrase issue. It's a good point.

Comment: Does it have to be one single regexp?

Comment: @damienfrancois, actually the number of single quotes is _even_.  You overlooked that `it's` ;-)

Comment: @damienfrancois no, does not need to be a single regexp.

Comment: Did you notice that ``“Give a man .... for a lifetime,”`` and ``“On two occasions, .... such a question.”`` have curly quotation glyphs (also said typographic) ,
while ``"played off stage"`` and  ``"I said, this is going to be big."`` and ``"My friends .... 'it's just a cat.'"`` have typewriter quotation glyphs (also said straight, vertical, neutral or dumb). What about this point ?

Comment: Isn't the punctuation …`to be big.", he says`… wrong?  I think it should be just `to be big", he says` or maybe `to be big," he says`.  Full stops are omitted at the end of a quoted part in case the sentence continues with a comma, aren't they?

Comment: Again, great point, the expected punctuation will be " instead of “, I have fixed that now.

Comment: The interest of this point lies in the fact that curly quotations marks are different at the left and at the right of a quotation, and the it's easier to detect a quotation, while it's more difficult in the case of vertical quotation marks because it is required to count them I think.

Comment: The pattern ``[A-Z].*?\".*?\".*?\.`` expresses that a matchiing string must begin with a capital letter and end with a dot, and that there must be two vertical quotation marks in it: these elements are anchors; the rest isn't mandatory. So why do you write  ``I need to make sure that the quote is appearing in a sentence `` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you ?

Note tha I edited my first answer that was stupid because the regx in it was matching all the sentences, not opnly the ones with quotations marks.
i also take account of Alve's remark: The sentences catched by the regex doesn't begin only with a capital, but just by the first character after a dot, apart from a blank or `\r` or `n` or possible additional dots

```
import re
regx = re.compile('(?!\Z)'
                  '[. \n\r]*'
                  '('
                    '(?:[^."]*"[^"]*")+'
                    '[^."]*'
                    '(?:\.|\Z)'
                  ')')

s = ('''\nThe "some.rutu"  and "oula oulah, poto."  are '''
     '''all good. A "bi'didi."  is not.  I '''
     """don't know why... 5 "million" people """
     """died . \nAnd here's a sentence without """
     """a quote. "Halt!" he shouted. 'Sunny """
     """days and "nights"'  is a strange phrase""")
print s
print
for el in regx.findall(s):
    print '- %s' % el
```

result

```
The "some.rutu"  and "oula oulah, poto."  are all good. A "bi'didi."  is not.  I don't know why... 5 "million" people died . 
And here's a sentence without a quote. "Halt!" he shouted. 'Sunny days and "nights"'  is a strange phrase

- The "some.rutu"  and "oula oulah, poto."  are all good.
- A "bi'didi."  is not.
- 5 "million" people died .
- "Halt!" he shouted.
- 'Sunny days and "nights"'  is a strange phrase
```

Comment: This looks like a significant improvement on my pattern. One minor detail: I noticed that it is ignoring multiple carriage returns. So it will match a quote and then the first sentence from the line after the multiple carriage returns.

Comment: Do you mean; in case there is only one quotation mark in a line ? In such a case, it's true that any subsequent dot after this quotation mark won't be detected by the regex as a dot ending a sentence. So that's right, the matching will skip any newline. **Any** nexline; that means one or several additional lines, or even possibly until the end of the text if there's no more quotation mark until the end. But is a whole text supposed to have only one quotation mark ?

Comment: Another question : is a line supposed not to have only one quotation mark but at least two ?

Comment: Just updated the question with an example with multiple carriage returns.

Comment: Accepting this answer since it brought me closest to what I want to do and vastly improved on what I was doing originally. Thanks @eyquem

Comment: Thank you. I don't think the problem is over, I would like to work on it more but these times I have not enough time. I wish to come on it again as soon as possible. - By the way, I'm surprised that in your question, you continue to define the sentences you want to catch as beginning with a capital letter, though my regex, modified after Alfe's remark, is able to catch even sentences beginning with, for example, a number or a quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do cannot be done using regular expressions.

Natural language is a complicated thing, even the written one is not as easy as it seems.  There are several things I want to point out to make clear what special cases are grounding my conclusion:

> He landed — thud! — on the ground.

---

> "Halt!" he shouted.

---

> 5 million people died.

I have no idea how these examples could be matched with a pure regexp for sentences of natural languages.

EDIT:

It should be next to impossible for a computer to distinguish between these two cases:

> After that he said, "Never again!" Then he left the room.

---

> He hit on the table, "Never again!" Peter said, and left the room.

On a character level both look exactly of the same kind (capital after quotes, etc.) but the first should be parsed into two sentences, the second into one.  It is up to a understanding intelligence like a human being to see that both cases are different.  The technical characters do not display this.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I was originally using nltk to split the sentences and then look at them, but since it splits sentences in a very rigid way I decided to try using regex instead. Even though it won't be perfect, I would be happy to improve on the regex pattern I have.

Comment: @Alfe You mean that ``"Halt!" he shouted.`` and ``5 million people died.`` won't be catched because they don't begin with a capital letter ? Concerning the first, there are no quotation marks, what do you mean with this sample ?

Comment: Yes, one aspect of all my examples is that they contradict the naïve approach of specifying "A sentence starts with a capital letter, contains only letters and non-enders (commas, hyphens, …) and ends with an ender (full-stop, exclamation mark, question mark, …)."

Comment: I added two more examples which make clear that a mere character-wise parsing won't succeed in recognizing sentences correctly in all cases.

Comment: The example in your edit is very fine. I completely agree with you: a program can't differentiate two portions of text (one with one sentence, the other with two sentences) on the basis of their sense when it is written to differentiate texts on a the basis of their characters. **I don't think it could be PERFECTLY possible** to code the program so as it could differentiate between your two cases anyway. For example, we may list all the first names as Peter, Alan, Christel, Anna and so forth and to treat the cases differently if a capital letter belongs to one of them or not;

Comment: I don't think that a lookout for names would help a lot.  Consider: `After that he said, "Never again!" Peter left the room in a fury.`  I think instead that you'd need to go much deeper into natural language processing or live with errors in cases like these.

Comment: Also, things like `Take e. g. Peter's car.` vs. `We found the solution in the Book Of Math, 1968, Miller et. al. Peter liked it a lot.`.  Even non-English speakers would be hard pressed to see where the sentences end in cases like these.

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted badly written comments that didn't express correctly what I wanted to say. I tried to delete them but just at this moment my internet connection failed so the above comment remains. Here after is what I wanted to say :

Comment: The example in your edit is very fine. I completely agree with you: a program can't differentiate two portions of text (one with one sentence, the other with two sentences) on the basis of their sense when it is coded to differentiate texts on the basis of their characters.
However, I have two remarks:

Comment: **1/** I don't think it could be PERFECTLY possible to code the program so as it could differentiate between your two cases. But in some extent, this goal can be approached. For example, we may list all the first names as Peter, Alan, Christel, Anna and so forth and to treat the cases differently if a capital letter belongs to one of them or not; or we could consider that some words as 'what', 'the', 'a', 'next' etc are first word of a sentence if their first letter is capital; and I don't know what kind of other similar tricks.

Comment: So, in some extent, it is IMPERFECTLY possible to make a program able to act particularly in particular cases. I suppose it's the kind of work (taking in account the sense of words) that has been done for NLTK (I don't know NLTK precisely). This kind of improvement will never be perfect, for it is impossible to confine a natural language in a model with a finite number of rules, but it can be approached. That's what I think.

Comment: **2/** In the case of your two portions of text, it must be considered that it isn't the fault of the program if it doesn't give the good result on a characters basis, since it is clear that the writing of the first text doesn't respect what should be the correct way to write it, that is to say with a dot in front of "Then". And then your example isn't entirely convincing. Which doesn't invalidate the core of what you say. But the program must not be made responsible of what it isn't responsible of.

Comment: I didn't understand your argument about a dot in front of "Then".  Can you explain that?  There is no dot in front of the "Then"; do you assume there should be a dot?  There's an exclamation mark in the quoted part before it, so no dot should appear.  What do you mean?

Comment: I don't see why there's a dot after ``et`` in ``Miller et.`` . Is it shorting for ``Miller et allii`` ? - I don't see the difference between ``He hit on the table, "Never again!" Peter said, and left the room.`` and ``After that he said, "Never again!" Peter left the room in a fury.`` though it's seems to me that in the second one, the comma should be after the quote, not in front of. These two sentences are correctly catched by my code.

Comment: Take in mind that I am french and I don't seize all the subtleties of english. The first portion of text seems to me to be incorrect because I understand it could be either ``After that he said "Never again!" , then he left the room.`` (meaning _After that he had said_ but that's probably a misunderstanding of mine polluted by the fact that in french it would be _Après qu'il ait dit_ ) OR ``After that, he said: "Never again!", and then he left the room"``. Anyway, in the two cases I feel there must not be a capital letter for **the**. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, the dot after `et` was plain wrong, sorry, strip that, not necessary for the example.  The trouble is the dot after the `al` (which means `alii`, right).  Without _understanding_ the meaning it is next to impossible to find out if such a dot ends a sentence or just an abbreviation.  The difference between the two examples is that the first clearly is one sentence, the second is two sentences, separated at the end of the quote.  English does not provide dots or commas after quotes which end on exclamation marks or question marks (so there is no `!",` or `?".` anywhere).

Comment: I don't know much about French, but in German just recently ("Rechtschreibreform") they introduced the commas after quotes ending on question marks etc.  Older books do also not have those.  And dots after such quotes don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern worked for me in ruby.  Should be fine in python once you convert it to r''

`/([a-zA-Z,\' ]+\"[^.]+\.)/`

Elliott